# How to insert numbers from line into array in Collection

Tags: c#, arrays, collections

I have a list, every line looks like this:

```
CAR 1Z2 13 84 ... (200 hundred numbers) ...  ZG2 // splitted by space
.
. 
.
Repeated lines (around 1000 lines with different numbers)
```

and my Collection:

```
public class Test 
{
public string A { set; get; } // first value of line
public string B { set; get; } // second value of line
public double[] C { set; get; } // values[2-200]
public string A { set; get; } // last value of line
}
```

There is my part of solution:

```
List<Test> test = new List<Test>();

foreach (string s in list)
        {
            var values = s.Split(null);

            test.Add(new Test
            {
                A = values[0],
                B = values[1],
                C = double.Parse(values[2-200]), // ??
                D = values[201],
            });
        }
```

How can I insert values [2-200] into C array in Collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Linq, skips the first 2 values and take the next 199 values, apply the parsing conversion to this sequence and materialize the array.

```
C = values.Skip(2).Take(199).Select(x => double.Parse(x)).ToArray();
```